# Why does chrome terminate most tcp connections with RST?

Tags: google-chrome, tcp

Currently making a tool to track TCP connections.
Testing with chrome, I found that quite a lot of connections were terminated with RST instead of just the normal FIN routine.

[image]

Rows in red are (partially or not) terminated connections. The first column is src ports(ip is always the same), the second column is dst ips and ports. The first column of arrows is just a "from to" whereas the second is the direction of the last packet sent (left = server to client, right = otherwise).
After the bars there are codes indicating the status of the connection. These are defined like so:

[image]

ST means status, HS means handshake, and F termination (fin)
9 is only for connections terminated with RST
8 means of course a successful complete termination.

---

Maybe worth mentioning, only connections with a successful handshake are listed. This is C and I'm using a linked list to store connections I captured the SYN packet of.

From what I've read RST is sent when a connection is lost but looking at the table, we can see that well over half the connection terminations are through RST. Why is that?